# Google App Engine can't connect to Cloud SQL after being deployed

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I am running into problems deploying my Wordpress site to Google App Engine (GAE).  When I use Web Preview in the Cloud Shell local development environment, everything works fine.  I use this code in `db.php` to provide a different path to the `wp-config.php` file depending on whether the app is operating from the local development environment or from the GAE environment:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_ENV'])) {
    require_once '/srv/wp-config.php';
} else {
    require_once '../../../../wp-config.php';
}
```

My Wordpress site works perfectly when working locally, meaning that I am able to query the database, so both the path to `wp-config.php` is correct, and the database parameters must also be correct.

I followed this tutorial Wordpress on GAE Standard and it modified the `wp-config.php` file so that we now provide different database parameters, depending on the environment:

```
if ($onGae) {
  /** The name of the Cloud SQL database for WordPress */
  define('DB_NAME', 'myDB');
  /** Production login info */
  define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/myProject:us-central1:myInstance');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'myPassword');
} else {
  /** The name of the local database for WordPress */
  define('DB_NAME', 'myDB');
  /** Local environment MySQL login info */
  define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
  define('DB_USER', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'myPassword');
}
```

My next step is to use `google app deploy` and test the app in the GAE environment.  The Wordpress site loads, but throws this error when doing a database search:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

It seems like my database parameters can connect to Cloud SQL from the local development environment, but when it is deployed to GAE, the specified database parameters are not working.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Could you provide the file structure of the application? Furthermore, I assume you are able to do a database search in the local development since `everything worked fine`, is this correct? In any case, I also suggest you look at these two documentations, which may help you in troubleshooting or find a workaround to the issue: [Wordpress on GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard) and [Wordpress on GAE Flex](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible)

Comment: Thanks @JKleinne, I did follow the Wordpress on GAE Standard tutorial and got it working.  Now I am trying to get another Wordpress site running properly on GAE.  I resolved the earlier issue about the different paths to the wp-config.php file, depending on the environment..  Now the issue is connecting to Cloud SQL after depoying to GAE.

Comment: No worries @DanielAttard . In any case, this type of error message occur when it cannot find the host's public nameserver record, which is intended to limit the number of servers having access to the instance. I would suggest reading through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-sql) which will walk you through the process of using CloudSQL with appengine.